# Convert sql function to c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Hi all I am having an sql function where some part of it is used to convert varchar to datetime:

```
IF @dt IS NULL
    SET @dt = GETDATE();

SET @PDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, @PValue + '-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4),YEAR(@dt))); 
IF @PDate > @dt
    SET @Year = YEAR(@dt) - 1;
ELSE
    SET @Year = YEAR(@dt);

RETURN (SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @PValue + '-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4),@Year)));
```

Can some one help me?

My value of `@PValue` is `01-APRIL`.

I just declare Datetime as follows in my C# code:

```
DateTime? dt=null;

if(!(dt.HasValue))
    dt=DateTime.Now;
```

But after this I was confused to do the remaining.

Comment: If I am not wrong `SET @PDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, @PValue + '-' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4),YEAR(@dt))); ` will display `01-APRIL-YEAR`

Answer (score 1):

You could do with a year field in order to convert properly, I can't see `01-APRIL` being a valid date. `01-APRIL` when? Once you have a valid structured datetime, your `C#` code will read:

```
string pValue = @"01/04";
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
pValue += string.Format(@"/{0}", now.Year);
int year = 0;
if (DateTime.TryParse(pValue, ref dt))
{
  if (dt > now)
    year = dt.Year -1
  else
    year = dt.Year;
}
```

Comment: Hi my pvalue is `01-APRIL` this I need to convert to datetime

Comment: @Learner you can't have that as `DateTime` not even a `Date`, not reliably anyway because there isn't a year.

Comment: @Learner I see that you are getting your `Year` from `DateTime.Now` so you date isn't `01-APRIL` it is `01-APRIL-2013`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a string to a date, then you should use the `DateTime.Parse` method. You should probably declare the parameter as a `string`, not `DateTime?`.

Comment: Hi for the function I will pass dateTime value that is not the issue here as per said my value will be `01-APRIL` how can I convert this datetime in C# as per the query in SQL

Answer (score 0):

Just call `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact`, never parse dates yourself because you will have a bug in your implementation. It's one of life's certainties, like death and taxes.

If you use `Parse` and not `ParseExact` be sure to specify a `CultureInfo` because `03/06/99` will be parsed differently if the current locale is English (United States) as opposed to English (United Kingdom).

Answer (score 0):

something like below

```
DateTime? dt = null;
        int pYear = 2012; // assuming pYear is getting populated from somewhere
        int finalYear = 1900; // initilizing some value to it;
        if (!(dt.HasValue))
            dt = DateTime.Now;
        var year = dt.Value.Year;
        var pValue = "1-Apr";
        if (pYear > year)
            finalYear = pYear - 1;
        else
        {
            finalYear = year;
        }

        return pValue + finalYear.ToString();
```